# How to add CSS stylesheet to aspx.vb table

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have created a search button that when clicked it will display the details of the search into a table format but i need help in getting the table to look like a table and look presentable.

i'm struggling to work out how i go about this as im new to asp.net. I do have a stylesheet linked to my .aspx page and this is my OnCLick event handler code;

```
 Protected Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     SearchButton.Click
    Dim dsResults As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTableReader



    dsResults = SearchResults(sbox1.Text)
    dt = dsResults.CreateDataReader


    Dim tb As New Table
    Dim tr As New TableRow
    Dim tc As New TableCell
    Dim lb As New Label

    tb.Attributes.Add("class", "tableClass")
    tr.Attributes.Add("class", "tableRowClass")

    If dt.HasRows = True Then
        Do While dt.Read

            tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("name").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)



            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("age").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)



            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("sex").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)



            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("department").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)



            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("list_group").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)



            tc = New TableCell
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("date_added").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)

            tb.Controls.Add(tr)
        Loop
        dt.Close()
        dsResults.Dispose()

        placeResults.Controls.Add(tb)

    Else

        noResultOutput.Text = "No Results Matched Your Search"

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone please help me in how i can add a class or something to link to my stylesheet so my table looks good. I have attempted to add a class above but nothing happens if i add this to my stylesheet.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use css selector for `table, tr, td, tbody` and apply required style. Because ultimately that renders as `<table> <tr> <td> ..`

Following are some of examples. Use this in `.aspx` .

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

More info - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: Would i just add the style straight to my stylesheet? Do i not need to reference the style on the aspx.vb page at all?

Comment: @user2982634 Yes, you should add this directly to stylesheet. Nothing need to be done in aspx.vb.

Comment: i added this to my styleshheet and saved it but nothing happens on my search page. I know this would work if i added a table on the HTML side but was wondering on the reference as my table is serverside

Comment: Do you have tables in aspx, when you looked into page, or are they built on some action? if so, then make that action happen and then check if styles applied.

Comment: I don't have the table in .aspx I am using a PlaceHolder in aspx to show the table when the search button is pressed. So the table only shows when the a user enters a name and presses the search button.

Comment: Ok, then press search button, then table will be shown and style should get applied, to double check , view the source if aspx page after pressing button, if it has table, and use some css debugging tool such as chrome inspector or firebug, to see if css is applied